# Como retirar corchetes de consulta

Tags: php, laravel

Hay alguna forma de retirar los corchetes que se retornan en la siguiente consulta?:

```
$useractivity=DB::table('user_category_activity')
           ->select('user_id',
           'category_activity_id',
           'state_id',
           'updated_at',
           'created_at',
           'id')
           ->where('user_id', $request->user_id)
           ->where('category_activity_id', $id)
           ->where('state_id', 1)
           ->get();

       return $useractivity;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La necesidad de retirar los corchetes va en que necesito que esta consulta sea exactamente igual a la siguiente:

```
 $activity = User_Category_activity::create([
        'user_id'=>$request->user_id,
        'category_activity_id'=>$id,
        'state_id'=>1
    ]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un servicio donde, dependiendo de la condición, me retorna alguna de estas dos consultas, pero para el front-end, esto debe ser totalmente transparente y por ello requiero que las consultas sean exactamente iguales.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es solamente un registro entonces puedes usar el metodo `first()` en lugar de `get()`

```
    $useractivity=DB::table('user_category_activity')
           ->select('user_id',
           'category_activity_id',
           'state_id',
           'updated_at',
           'created_at',
           'id')
           ->where('user_id', $request->user_id)
           ->where('category_activity_id', $id)
           ->where('state_id', 1)
           ->first(); // <- este

    return json_encode($useractivity);
```

Si no estoy equivocado regresa los corchetes porque es una coleccion, porque el metodo `get()` regresa una coleccion independientemente de el numero de resultados, en cambio el metodo `first()` regresa un objecto, lo que causa que no tenga los corchetes.

Comment: Es que si no estoy equivocado le regresa los corchetes porque es una coleccion, porque el metodo `get()` regresa una coleccion independientemente de el numero de resultados, en cambio el metodo `first()` regresa un objecto, lo que causa que no tenga los corchetes.

Comment: Genera el siguiente error:          UnexpectedValueException: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Comment: Funciona si agregas ->toArray() al return? osea `return $useractivity->toArray();`

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()

Comment: Ok, entonces creo que asi debe funcionar `return json_encode($useractivity);`

Comment: No necesitas `json_encode`, Laravel ya ofrece esto así `response()->json();`

Comment: Funcionó, mil gracias :)

Comment: Consejo @Jeiyana utiliza mejor el orm y menos el query builder